# How do you participate in a private beta on area51

Tags: support, area-51, private-beta

I committed to following a new site, but there doesn't seem to be any way to interact or ask questions now that the site is in private beta.

Comment: Which site please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you visit the propsal now there should be a "Visit the Site now" link there. You also should have gotten an email with a link to the new site.

This is an example from the most recently launched Biology site, see the "Visit the site now!" link.

[image]

Comment: Thats public beta.... **not** private beta

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA No, Biology is still in private beta.

Comment: @Fabian Only users that *committed* to the private beta, such as yourself, see the "Visit the site now!" while it's still in private beta.

Comment: Yes, there is tiny "visit" box that is easy to miss.  I thought I made it clear that I committed in private beta.  This answer wins.

Answer (score 5):

If you didn't **commit** to the proposal *before* it entered private beta, the only* way to participate in the site is to wait until it enters public beta.

<sup>* Or, someone already in the private beta can invite you</sup>