# Difference between private and public beta

Tags: discussion, private-beta, beta-badge

The 'Beta' badge is gained if a user actively participates in a private beta.

But I don't know how and where to participate in a private beta.

What is a private beta site?

I have 3 stack exchange beta accounts(Islam, Sports, Askdifferent).

I understand that they are public betas rather than private ones.

I found this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116633/how-do-you-participate-in-a-private-beta-on-area51) but the explanation there was not helpful.

What is the difference between a private and a public beta?

How do I get an account in a private beta?

Comment: Don't roll back grammar fixes. "Differnce" is NOT a valid word in English and having millions of mistakes do not make it valid.

Comment: but, there is no grammar fixes, it's just a spelling correction from 'Differnce' to 'Difference'

Comment: Grammar, spelling.. doesn't matter: why roll back totally valid edit to your post which makes it better?

Comment: hmm..........ok

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Private Beta is the phase that precedes Public Beta**. So if some site is already on public beta, you can't 'create a private beta account'.

To participate in private beta you'd have to commit to the proposal on area 51, before the site is launched. Then the site will go into private beta for about a week (during which users who did not commit can only participate if invited by some user who had commited and is participating), being only available to the users that had committed before. After that period you will be able to participate in public beta, which is the phase in which the site is still 'being tested', but everyone can visit it and participate.
This is explained in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116664/208518).

But I actually don't know how to earn the Beta badge, since I (along with other users) participated in [Anime and Manga](http://anime.stackexchange.com)'s private beta, but no-one has been awarded that badge.

Comment: You have to have been active "enough" during the private beta, not just a member.  If nobody on the site has the badge though, it's possible the [beta badge script wasn't run properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64152/no-beta-badges-generated-on-cstheory-sx) and you could ask about that.

Comment: @Troyen Thanks, already made a [post at meta.anime&manga](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/329/49)