# Do I have any chance now to get a beta badge for stack overflow

Tags: discussion, support

As per these responses:

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188731/163149
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105/163149
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164192/163149

Beta tag can be earned only participating in private beta. So do I have any chance of getting this badge for Stack Overflow, in future?

Comment: No, you do not have any chance.

Comment: Buy one on Ebay.

Comment: @Shog9 Are [Precognitive](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/892/precognitive) badges available anywhere? ;-) I heard those are really in demand.

Comment: You can build a time machine, create account when Stack Overflow was in Beta and you'll have the badge. :)

Comment: @Shog9 Please provide the link from where you have got one. ;) :P

Comment: @Sha Wiz Dow Ard, I like idea of Shog more than yours.. you really need to work on simplifying the solutions

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Thats the obvious solution. You should try thinking outside the box :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## No.

You are a few years too late.

Another one that cant be earned is [Precognitive](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/892/precognitive), in case you were wondering.

Comment: *gasp* You used a post length workaround! The unicorns will never forgive you! :P

Comment: OKAY AsheeshR, I got it, you don't need to scold me in large bolds!!

Comment: Also worth to mention that chances to get [Unsung Hero](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/70/unsung-hero) badge here on Meta are really really really low, as users **always** vote, either up or down!!

Answer (score 3):

**No.**

You might be confused about what "beta" means in this context. In spite of being a software related site, this has nothing to do with the software powering the site. Unlike the release process for new versions of software where pre-release test versions are known as "betas", the term "beta" in the context of SE sites refers to the process of setting up the community and scoping out the overall subject matter of the site, not the software. The beta phase is when people that were interested in the topic get together and demonstrate what questions can and cannot be asked inside the scope of the site. This is a phase that sites go through once, then eventually graduate. No matter how many iterations of the software happen, the process of picking a subject matter for a site and building up the initial community is only done once.

Once the beta period is over, it's never coming back. StackExchange is not a time machine. A limited number of badges could only be earned if you were in the right place at the right time. They were on-time-shots. If you didn't participate in the beta stage, you don't get a beta badge. End of story.

You could however earn a beta badge for another site by participating on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) and finding a proposal you are interested in that is going into beta.

Comment: Hey, I beg to differ. TARDIS.SE

Comment: @Emrakul Time has not been kind to [TARDIS.SE](http://tardis.stackexchange.com/). "_The Q&A site tardis.stackexchange.com doesn't seem to exist…yet._"

Comment: Yeah, for sure, but as every iOS update have it's beta I thought, may be stackoverflow updated will have the same.

Comment: @Caleb Oh my gods that is absolutely brilliant.

Comment: @rptwsthi No, the "beta" stage is for forming the community and the scope of the site, not a release of the software. Read up on this process on Area 51.