# Do users really have to be committed to proposals to post in the private beta?

Tags: support, private-beta, commitment

The [Tezos](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/120123/tezos) proposal just recently entered private beta. Supposedly, [users have to commit to the proposal to participate during the private beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164191/difference-between-private-and-public-beta/164192#164192). However, I tried posting on Tezos using [an account](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/users/353/user10931531) on which I hadn't committed to the proposal, yet I was still able to post an answer! (check [here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/120123?phase=commitment) if you don't believe the account wasn't committed)

[image: Screenshot of answer]

Is this intentional and there has been some change to allow non-committed users to participate in the private beta, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, non-committers can indeed participate in the private beta, *provided* they access the site through the Area 51 proposal page. If they try to access the site from a direct link, the site switcher, or any other source, they will not be permitted entry.

Once one accesses the site through Area 51 and joins the community, then they can access the site through any means.

[It appears this is intentional](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212235/why-am-i-allowed-to-sign-up-on-a-private-beta-site-i-never-commited-to). The fact that you are unable to review close votes if you are not committed is likely a bug, since it only requires 1 reputation, and you should file a separate bug report for that.